# Basic GridView backed with a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a list of names and (optional) links to my ASP.net page.

I learnt (hopefully) to use a GridView to do this, mostly working from the example given by this blog entry: [adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview](https://web.archive.org/web/20200129202515/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/08/03/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textbox-and-dropdownlist.aspx).

I've added a GridView to my frontend:

```asp
<asp:GridView
        id="NameLinksGridView" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Link" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button 
                    ID="addNameLink" runat="server"
                    Text="Add" onclick="addNameLink_Click"
                    CausesValidation="false" />
            </FooterTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

With the code behind:

```cs
private void setupInitialNameLinks()
{
    DataTable dt = getNameLinksTable();
    /* store DataTable in the ViewState for preservation across PostBack's */
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    /* bind the displayed DataGrid to our DataTable */
    NameLinksGridView.DataSource = dt;
    NameLinksGridView.DataBind();
    /* set current TextBox values to the values in the DataTable 
        * surely the DataBind should do this for us?!? */
    setTextBoxValuesToDataTableValues(dt);
}

private DataTable getNameLinksTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Link", typeof(string)));

    var existingNameLinks = getExistingNameLinks();
    if (existingNameLinks.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var auth in existing)
        {
            DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
            r["Name"] = auth.name;
            r["Link"] = auth.link;
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DataRow emptyRow = getNameLinksEmptyRow(dt);
        dt.Rows.Add(emptyRow);
    }
    return dt;
}

private static DataRow getNameLinksEmptyRow(DataTable dt)
{
    DataRow emptyRow = dt.NewRow();
    emptyRow["Name"] = String.Empty;
    emptyRow["Link"] = String.Empty;
    return emptyRow;
}

protected void addNameLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable) ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow dr = getNameLinksEmptyRow(dt);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        /* update our DataTable to the POST'ed data */
        int numPostedRows = dt.Rows.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPostedRows; i++)
        {
            TextBox tbName = 
                (TextBox)NameLinksGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Name");
            string name = tbName.Text; // get POST'ed value
            dt.Rows[i]["Name"] = name; // set DataTable val to the POST'ed value
            TextBox tbLink = 
                (TextBox)NameLinksGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("Link");
            string link = tbLink.Text;
            dt.Rows[i]["Link"] = link;
        }

        /* store our DataTable in the ViewState for preservation across PostBack */
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        /* bind the displayed DataGrid to our DataTable */
        NameLinksGridView.DataSource = dt;
        NameLinksGridView.DataBind();

        /* set current TextBox values to the values in the DataTable
            * needs to happen after the DataBind()
            * surely the DataBind should do this for us?!? */
        setTextBoxValuesToDataTableValues(dt);

    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("CurrentTable is null!");
    }
}

private void setTextBoxValuesToDataTableValues(DataTable dt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tbName = (TextBox)NameLinksGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Name");
        tbName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
        TextBox tbLink = (TextBox)NameLinksGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("Link");
        tbLink.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Link"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Does any of this code look troublesome, prone to error, umnaintanable, not the right way of doing it, etc?

One big bit of confusion I have (even though the code works) — why do I need to store the DataTable in the ViewState manually and set my TextBox displayed values manually (in `setTextBoxValuesToDataTableValues`)? Surely the GridView state should be maintained across the POST without me needing to worry about the ViewState and the DataBind should set the TextBox values automatically?

Comment: The KetticGridView is capable of [populating gridview with data using DataTable](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_populate_data_binding_datatable.shtml) to a single data table or dataset, as well as to multiple data tables through hierarchical data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding having to get/set the value of the textboxes, you should get to know the `Bind` expression. For instance, you could have:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
```

For one of the "right" ways of doing things, have a look at [this walkthrough of bulk editing rows in the GridView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036.aspx).